# Learning About the lib Directory in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to Rails, and am trying to learn how the `/lib/` directory in Rails works - and how to reference variables defined in the `/lib/` directory for use in a view.

I have a file called `helloworld.rb` and it's saved in the /lib/ directory in Rails.

The `helloworld.rb` file has the following code:

```
module HelloWorld
  def hello
    @howdy = "Hello World!"
  end
end
```

I want to be able to display the results of this method on a view called `index.html.erb`, so I include the following code in the `index_helper.rb` file:

```
module IndexHelper
  require 'helloworld'
end
```

Also, I include the following code on the view `index.html.erb`:

```
<%= @howdy %>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call Helloworld::hello in order for it to create your instance variable.

maybe you could put it in a before_filter in your controller

```
require 'helloworld'

class FooController < Application::Controller

  before_filter :setup_hello , [:only=>:create, :edit ]
  def create
     # whatever
  end
  def edit
     #whatever
  end
  def setup_hello
    HelloWorld::hello
  end
end
```

So now,  every time you either your edit or create action, 'setup_hello' is executed,  which calls the hello method in your module,  and sets the @hello instance variable.

Comment: I must be missing something... When I implement this in my controller, I get the following error: undefined method `hello' for Helloworld:Module

Comment: Hmmm... I must still be doing something wrong, as I get the same error message. The error message points to the line in the controller that references `Helloworld::hello`.

Also, am I correct to assume that in the View, I can reference this code by using: `<%= setup_hello %>` ?

Comment: Fixed ANOTHER typo ('HelloWorld') vs ('Helloworld') and added more context and explanation.

Comment: NoMethodError in ReportsController#index

    undefined method 'hello' for HelloWorld:Module
    Rails.root: C:/rails_projects/helloworld

    app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:8:in `setup_hello'

Comment: Thanks Brad. Combined with your help and my other posting on this subject (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260387/using-lib-subdirectories-in-rails-for-view-content), I was able to figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

You should any of these lines to `config/application.rb` file.

```
module [App name]
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Dir.glob("./lib/*.rb").each { |file| require file } 
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib)
  end
end
```

Uncomment any of commented lines. Both of them do same work.

`Dir.glob` finds all .rb files in app and require each file in rails app.

Also `config.autoload_paths` also load all files in lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the lib folder to the auto-load path in config/application.rb

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
# config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Comment: I found that this auto-load step wasn't necessary as long as I'm requiring the file in my Controller.